# Replace parameter value using sed or awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have some configuration file like example

```
 A_place = 10km
 B_place=5km
 #A_place=2km
 C_place=1km
```

I want to change the A_place value in the uncommented line. Some of the lines may have initial spaces. I tried a basic `sed` command to find and replace it but it didn't work. Perhaps I should use  `AWK` rather than stream editor?

Comment: Why did you tag C? Please post the `sed` commands you tried. Also post the result you got, and what you wanted.

Comment: Given the lack of precision in the question, a reasonable answer would be "Use the correct sed command".

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using sed:

`sed -e '/#/!s/\(A_place[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1"new_value"/'  input`

breakdown of what is being done here:

skip lines that are comments:

**/#/!**

Then comes the substitution in the form

*s/old/new/*

Select the old, and put the original string inside parens (backreferencing) so that it can be retained later by specifying \1. This matches the string "A_place" followed by zero or more whitespace chars followed by the equal sign followed by zero more more whitespaces chars. Note that the value to be replaced is also in parens and could be referenced by \2; it is not needed here and the parens can be left off. So the old string to match is:

**(** A_place[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]* **)** (.*)

Then the new line to output is created using the "\1" backref, preserving the whitespace around the equals sign and appending the "new value", shown here with quotation marks for clarity which are a literal in the new line but probably not wanted in the final output. "\1" here is everything that was matched in the first paren delimited regex, including any whitespace around the equals sign:

\1"new_value"

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '!/#/{sub(/A_place/,"new_value")} 1'  Input_file
```

***OR in case OP wants to change the `A_place` string's last column value then use:***

```
awk '!/#/ && /A_place/{$NF="new_value"} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you have more than 1 occurrences of string `A_place` then change `sub` to `gsub`. Also if you want to save output into same Input_file then you could use following code too for same then.

```
awk '!/#/{sub(/A_place/,"new_value")} 1'  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '!/#/ && /A_place/{$NF="new_value"} 1'  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Comment: This replaces `A_place` with `new value`, but I guess the OP wants to keep `A_place =` and modify the distance.

Comment: @MOehm, thank you, I have added that solution too now in my post.

Comment: Yes, but your new variant doesn't work when there are no spaces around the equals sign. (The `A_place` doesn't have them, but the other lines make it clear that this is valid syntax. You could make the `=` the field separator, though.)

Answer (score 1):

The following sed expression will set the new distance of `A_place` to 32km. The spaces of everything up to the new distance are retained:

```
> cat kk.config 
 A_place = 10km
 B_place=5km
 #A_place=2km
 C_place=1km

> sed -i -e 's/^\( *A_place *= *\).*/\132km/' kk.config 

> cat kk.config 
 A_place = 32km
 B_place=5km
 #A_place=2km
 C_place=1km
```

One of the problems with regular expressions is that there are so many flavours. Apparently, sed uses basic regexes and you have to backslash the parentheses if you want to group stuff for later back references. The caret will start matching from the beginning of the line and therefore ignore the match in comments.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution can be done with `awk` when we assume a couple of things:

1. Whitespace around `=` can always be removed
2. We will search for an exact match on the left hand side
3. Key values consist of a single unquoted word

With this we can create a small shell wrapper `run.sh` with the key and value as parameters:

```
key=$1
value=$2
awk -F '[ =]*' \
  -v key=$key \
  -v value=$value \
'/^#/ { print; next }
$1 == key { $2 = value }
  { print $1 "=" $2 }' sample.txt
```

Example run:

```
$ sh run.sh A_place 20km
A_place=20km
B_place=5km
#A_place=2km
C_place=1km
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `sed` solution:

```
val="2km"
sed "/^[[:blank:]]*A_place[[:blank:]]*=/s/=.*/= ${val}/" file
```